# Detecting App Information from User Agent using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

I have a Log file with attribute like :

```
 telcol;getInformation();;000000;Production;User-Agent=MyApp/0.3.4/Android/4.1.2/GT-I9300;HTTP-Statuscode=200;phoneNumber=;X-Statistic-Context=
```

How would I detect the App Name with version using regular expressions so that it would return e.g.

```
MyApp/0.3.4
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to get it via the semicolon delimiters, if the data is formatted like that?

Comment: yes , but i need the regexp because the information will be saved into a Datawarehouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
(?<=;user-agent=)([^/]+/[^/]+)
```

Comment: it's exactly what i want. Thank You !